# En Raspberry Pi - ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected

Tags: linux, debian, arm

Tengo una `Raspberry` en la que ejecuto varios demonios del tipo `(mldonkey,tor, i2pd...)` y suele ir bastante bien, hasta que un día de forma aleatoria deja de responder. La apago y la enciendo y siempre veo el mismo error en los logs:

> ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected

A partir de ese error el kernel comienza a conectar y desconectar cosas y es cuando la Raspberry no responde.

> Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.355203]
>   ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected Aug 16 19:59:43
>   raspi kernel: [68009.355203]
>   [277/352] Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.596912] usb 1-1: USB
>   disconnect, device number 2 Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel:
>   [68009.596944] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3 Aug 16
>   19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.597343] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0:
>   unregister 'smsc95xx' usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet
>   Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.597521] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0:
>   hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel:
>   [68009.627653] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4 Aug 16
>   19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.627683] usb 1-1.4.4: USB disconnect,
>   device number 5 Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.627701] usb
>   1-1.4.4.2: USB disconnect, device number 6 Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi
>   kernel: [68009.629303] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1):
>   ext4_end_bio:329: I/O error -5 writing to inode 2097237 (offset 0 size
>   0 starting block 40853774) Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel:
>   [68009.629331] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 40853509
>   Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.629356] Buffer I/O error on
>   device sda1, logical block 40853510 Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel:
>   [68009.629374] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 40853511
>   Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.629390] Buffer I/O error on
>   device sda1, logical block 40853512 Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel:
>   [68009.629407] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 40853513
>   Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.629424] Buffer I/O error on
>   device sda1, logical block 40853514 Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel:
>   [68009.629441] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 40853515
>   Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.629457] Buffer I/O error on
>   device sda1, logical block 40853516 Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel:
>   [68009.629474] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 40853517
>   Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.629819] Aborting journal on
>   device sda1-8. Aug 16 19:59:43 raspi kernel: [68009.629873] JBD2:
>   Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8. Aug 16
>   19:59:44 raspi kernel: [68010.132087] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing
>   SCSI cache Aug 16 19:59:44 raspi kernel: [68010.132363] sd 0:0:0:0:
>   [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x01
>   driverbyte=0x00 Aug 16 19:59:44 raspi kernel: [68010.346976] Indeed it
>   is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501 Aug 16 19:59:44 raspi kernel:
>   [68010.526767] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using
>   dwc_otg Aug 16 19:59:44 raspi kernel: [68010.527071] Indeed it is in
>   host mode hprt0 = 00001101 Aug 16 19:59:44 raspi kernel:
>   [68010.727215] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424,
>   idProduct=9514 Aug 16 19:59:44 raspi kernel: [68010.727249] usb 1-1:
>   New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0 Aug 16
>   19:59:44 raspi kernel: [68010.731243] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found Aug
>   16 19:59:44 raspi kernel: [68010.731704] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
>   Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel: [68011.006820] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed
>   USB device number 8 using dwc_otg Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel:
>   [68011.107300] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424,
>   idProduct=ec00 Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel: [68011.107339] usb 1-1.1:
>   New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0 Aug 16
>   19:59:45 raspi kernel: [68011.110751] smsc95xx v1.0.4 Aug 16 19:59:45
>   raspi kernel: [68011.172435] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register
>   'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet,
>   b8:27:eb:d2:9b:57 Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel: [68011.266803] usb
>   1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg Aug 16
>   19:59:45 raspi kernel: [68011.368445] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found,
>   idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608 Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel:
>   [68011.368479] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1,
>   SerialNumber=0 Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel: [68011.368495] usb 1-1.4:
>   Product: USB2.0 Hub Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel: [68011.370302] hub
>   1-1.4:1.0: USB hub found Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel: [68011.370877]
>   hub 1-1.4:1.0: 4 ports detected Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel:
>   [68011.646695] usb 1-1.4.4: new high-speed USB device number 10 using
>   dwc_otg Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel: [68011.748157] usb 1-1.4.4: New
>   USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608 Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi
>   kernel: [68011.748187] usb 1-1.4.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0,
>   Product=1, SerialNumber=0 Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel: [68011.748203]
>   usb 1-1.4.4: Product: USB2.0 Hub Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi kernel:
>   [68011.749792] hub 1-1.4.4:1.0: USB hub found Aug 16 19:59:45 raspi
>   kernel: [68011.750218] hub 1-1.4.4:1.0: 4 ports detected Aug 16
>   19:59:46 raspi kernel: [68012.026762] usb 1-1.4.4.2: new high-speed
>   USB device number 11 using dwc_otg Aug 16 19:59:46 raspi kernel:
>   [68012.128949] usb 1-1.4.4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0480,
>   idProduct=a208 Aug 16 19:59:46 raspi kernel: [68012.128979] usb
>   1-1.4.4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
>   Aug 16 19:59:46 raspi kernel: [68012.128996] usb 1-1.4.4.2: Product:
>   External USB 3.0 Aug 16 19:59:46 raspi kernel: [68012.129012] usb
>   1-1.4.4.2: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA Aug 16 19:59:46 raspi kernel:
>   [68012.129027] usb 1-1.4.4.2: SerialNumber: 20160107070195 Aug 16
>   19:59:46 raspi kernel: [68012.130759] usb-storage 1-1.4.4.2:1.0: USB
>   Mass Storage device detected Aug 16 19:59:46 raspi kernel:
>   [68012.132003] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.4.4.2:1.0 Aug 16 19:59:46
>   raspi kernel: [68012.519522] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't
>   capable of remote wakeup Aug 16 19:59:46 raspi kernel: [68012.519830]
>   IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready Aug 16 19:59:47
>   raspi kernel: [68013.131474] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA 
>   External USB 3.0 5438 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6 Aug 16 19:59:47 raspi kernel:
>   [68013.133021] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0 Aug 16
>   19:59:47 raspi kernel: [68013.135201] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029164
>   512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB) Aug 16 19:59:47 raspi
>   kernel: [68013.137088] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off Aug 16
>   19:59:47 raspi kernel: [68013.137126] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23
>   00 00 00 Aug 16 19:59:47 raspi kernel: [68013.137810] sd 1:0:0:0:
>   [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO
>   or FUA Aug 16 19:59:48 raspi kernel: [68013.955366] IPv6:
>   ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready Aug 16 19:59:48
>   raspi kernel: [68013.957382] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up,
>   100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1 Aug 16 19:59:51 raspi kernel:
>   [68017.750622]  sdb: sdb1 Aug 16 19:59:51 raspi kernel: [68017.757766]
>   sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk Aug 16 20:06:28 raspi kernel:
>   [68414.531360] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_find_entry:1451:
>   inode #2097153: comm mlnet: reading directory lblock 0 Aug 16 20:06:34
>   raspi kernel: [68420.200694] EXT4-fs error (device sda1):
>   ext4_find_entry:1451: inode #2097156: comm mlnet: reading directory
>   lblock 0 Aug 16 20:06:36 raspi kernel: [68422.725323] EXT4-fs error
>   (device sda1): ext4_find_entry:1451: inode #2097156: comm mlnet:
>   reading directory lblock 0 Aug 16 20:07:00 raspi kernel:
>   [68446.800855] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link down Aug 16 20:07:04
>   raspi kernel: [68450.672131] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up,
>   100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1

A la `Raspberry` sólo tengo conectado un ***hub*** ***usb*** con alimentación independiente y a ese mismo hub un disco duro por ***usb***. ¿Alguna de pista de como atajar el problema?

Comment: Creo que el problema está en la EXT4-fs error, verifica ese log, si es así me atrevería a decir que es el disco duro, puedes intentar con esto sudo lsblk -fm, verifica el nombre, size, group y mode, luego retira el disco duro y comprueba el funcionamiento.